# Locate android system key and sign apk

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to edit a system launcher apk but I need to sign it with a system key.

Does anyone know how I can find the system key in the firmware it came from?  I have no issues signing the apk, just need the system key.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: If it is not your app then you will have to ask the original publisher for the key, there is no other way.

Comment: The firmware itself does not have the keystore with the private key used for signing the firmware. The build server or developer machine that built the firmware would have that keystore.

Comment: Great, thanks guys.  At least I won't waste time hunting around for it :-)